# Can't Open Unity Project on Phone

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

Can't seem to open the area learning tutorial from google tango onto the android phone when I press build and run it successfully add the apk to the phone but the phone can't open the app.

Answer (score 0):

What phone are you using? Tango apps will only open on Tango enabled phones like the Asus Zenfone AR.

Comment: yes i am using the asus zenfone AR , its tango enabled. But whenever i tried to open the application it force closes. I followed the tutorial throughout

Comment: Which tutorial did you follow? I've found the ones on https://developers.google.com/tango/ don't always work correctly. Have you tried loading in the example scenes/projects from the SDK?

Comment: yes i did so its technically working on unity but crashes on the phone so i couldn't debug at all

Comment: If you have Android Studio's logcat open and your phone plugged in while you try and open the app you'll get some kind of error message saying why it's crashing.